# Pyspark JDBC writer: Appending to SQL table with truncate mode set to "true"?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

While working through some code at work, I noticed a specific pyspark code block:

```
df.write.format('jdbc')\
    .option("truncate","true")\
    .option( # connection credentials #)
    .mode('append').save()
```

I'm trying to understand if this is problematic. I unfortunately don't have the required credentials to test this code, but I can't wrap my head around the fact that it is both truncating and appending to a table.

I looked around for some resources but there's very limited [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) on Pyspark JDBC drivers, and even that doesn't really say too much about this.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Documentation you linked explained it:

> This is a JDBC writer related option. When SaveMode.Overwrite is enabled, this option causes Spark to truncate an existing table instead of dropping and recreating it.

Since your code uses append, not overwrite, the option will have no effect.